# NEW search vector

Tags: postgresql, triggers, full-text-search

```
BEGIN
    NEW.search_vector = ((setweight(
                             to_tsvector(
                                'pg_catalog.simple',
                                regexp_replace(
                                   coalesce(CAST(NEW.id AS TEXT), ''),
                                   '[-@.]', ' ', 'g'
                                )
                             ),
                             'B'
                          ) ||
                          setweight(
                             to_tsvector(
                                'pg_catalog.simple',
                                regexp_replace(
                                   coalesce(NEW.name, ''),
                                   '[-@.]', ' ', 'g'
                                )
                            ),
                            'A'
                          )) ||
                          setweight(
                             to_tsvector(
                                'pg_catalog.simple',
                                regexp_replace(
                                   coalesce(NEW.description, ''),
                                   '[-@.]', ' ', 'g'
                                )
                             ),
                             'C'
                          )) ||
                          setweight(
                             to_tsvector(
                                'pg_catalog.simple',
                                regexp_replace(
                                   coalesce(NEW.query, ''),
                                   '[-@.]', ' ', 'g'
                                )
                             ),
                             'D'
                          );
  RETURN NEW;
END
```

Can someone explain what the code above is doing?

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code, probably from a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on a table, takes four columns from the row about to be inserted, replaces certain special characters with spaces, constructs a text search vector using the `simple` text search configuration (no stemming, no stop words), assigns to them different weights so that hits rank differently, concatenates these text search vectors and assigns the result to a column.

The resulting column will probably have a text search index on it to speed up full text search.

Comment: It's part of a Create or replace function . I appreciate your help.  I'm trying to get a better understanding of PostgreSQL.